# what is name of this boolean mask, and which c# operators should I use to maximize performance?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

I would like to know the Boolean operator and\or operations that result in the following logic table. The value on the left is the input, the value on the right is the output.

```
00 => false
01 => true
10 => true
11 => false
```

I tried 11 and the AND operator. It results in the following logic table:

```
00 AND 11 = false
01 AND 11 = false
10 AND 11 = false
11 AND 11 = true
```

I tried 11 and the OR operator. It results in the following logic table:

```
00 OR 11 = true
01 OR 11 = true
10 OR 11 = true
11 OR 11 = true
```

Which boolean operator and\or boolean operations should I use to produce the desired results, and, is there any way to maximize performance? I'm using standard x64 Intel chipset and .Net 4.5.2.

Comment: "Desired" meaning that you should get `false` for `00 OR 11` and `11 OR 11`?

Comment: that's called an XOR

Comment: You are using operands 0 and 1 in your sample but the title and the result is boolean. In C language family the bitwise and bool operators are distingushed.

Comment: This part of the question is too vague to answer: "is there any way to maximize performance". Please clarify the intend/use/requirements.

Comment: I want to apply a mask(s) to achieve the same. Is that possible?

Comment: In terms or performance, I recall that some bool operations are faster than others, and the slow ones can be 'mapped' in to the fast ones, for example the xor operation is faster than a xand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [xor operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/zkacc7k1.aspx):

```
bool result = a ^ b;
```

So the full code would be:

```
bool a = (input & 1) == 1;
bool b = (input & 2) == 2;

bool result = a ^ b;
```

Comment: How would you use a bit mask(s) to accomplish the same? Notice that you are xor'ing the inputs, without applying a bit mask.

Answer (score 0):

This is exclusive OR (XOR)

Check out : 
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or](http://Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

Operator: ^  called XOR

[documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1(v=VS.80).aspx)